# Node / statSync issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm trying to log an array of numerically named sub-directories in "e:\subdirectory\" by using fs.statSync but I keep getting the error "module.exports" is not a function; to my understanding, this is exactly how I'm supposed to export the data

I'm using the synchronous version because I want the array to finish populating before it's exported.

this is for a "proof of concept", I plan on serving an html doc and pushing this array to an input field

here is the code...

### checke.js

```
var fs = require('fs');

function checkE() {
    for (var i = 1, accts = [], path = "e:\\subdirectory\\"; i <10000; i++ ) {
        var target = fs.statSynch(path + i.toString())
        if (target.isDirectory()) { accts.push(i) }
    }
}

module.exports(checkE)
```

### init.js

```
var checke = require('./checke.js')

console.log(checke)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign something to `module.exports` not call it like a function. [`module.exports` is an object](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports)

#### checke.js

```
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
    checkE: function checkE() {
       var accts = [];
       var path = 'e:\\subdirectory\\';

       for (var i = 1; i <10000; i++ ) {
           var target = fs.statSync(path + i.toString())
           if (target.isDirectory())
               accts.push(i);
       }

       return accts;
   }
}
```

#### init.js

```
var checke = require('./checke.js');
checke.checkE();
```

Comment: I've tried returning the array and exporting that, I've now moved the array out of the function scope, invoking the function and I'm still not sure what I'm doing wrong. New error "fs.statSynch is not a function"

Comment: `module.exports(accts) ` is not valid syntax

Comment: @ErikWaters there is no function `fs.statSynch()` its `fs.statSync()` see my updated answer

Comment: "checke.checkE is not a function", I'm not using try..catch to handle errors, could that be the issue here?

Comment: just had one of those epiphany moments thanks to this post -- like, of course m.e. is an object!